# how to add an entire folder to bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a folder with 2 files.  how do I push the entire folder to bitbucket?  My main objective is to have someone be able to download the entire folder.

In my terminal, I'm at the level where if I type `ls`, I can see the folder(named folder1) I want to commit.

```
git add folder1

git commit folder1

git push -u origin master
```

what I get is nothing (my bitbucket says No files in directory).
I tried

`git push -f origin master`

and no luck

Comment: update, okay I tried again bitbucket is still empty, but it does say it wrote 2 objects, which I think to mean it did it...but why can't I see it?

Comment: Is your folder empty? Git tracks only files. If that is the case, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/115983/5987698) might be useful.

Comment: I have 2 files that I want to commit, and since these 2 files are inside the folder,  I want to commit the entire folder.  do I need to be inside the folder1 and track everything inside first, and then go up one level and commit?

Comment: No, that should not be necessary. Are you sure those files are not set to be ignored by git, using a .gitignore file? What is the output of `git status`?

Comment: they are just 2 .py files.  output of git status is that branch is up to date and nothing to commit.

Comment: What’s the output of `git status --ignored`?

Comment: Also update the output of `git log` and `git show HEAD`

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that folder does not have a `.git` subfolder in it.
You would be adding/committing a nested repository, which would result in an empty folder on the remote side.

Second, make sure those files are not ignored with:

```
git check-ignore -v -- folder/aFile
```

Comment: thanks.  got it to work.  gave up and created a new folder and essentially just started over!